# Producer Consumer scenario with Reentrant Lock and Condition in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I have written a Producer Consumer program using Reentrant Lock and condition. It is working correctly, but I am not very sure whether implementation is correct. Moreover it does not seem to be optimal. Can somebody please verify if this is a correct implementation, moreover can you please tell, how to optimize it, like - taking lock at the place where it is really required

```
public class TestRL {

static class Observed {
    boolean filled = false;

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public boolean getFilled() {
        return filled;
    }
}

static Observed observed = new Observed();

static class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Observed observed;
    ReentrantLock lock;
    Condition condition;

    Consumer(Observed observed, ReentrantLock lock, Condition condition) {
        this.observed = observed;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                if (observed.getFilled() == false) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("consumer waiting");
                        condition.await();
                        System.out.println("consumed");

                        Thread.sleep(400 + 1000 * i % 2);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    observed.setFilled(false);
                    condition.signalAll();
                }else{
                    observed.setFilled(false);
                    condition.signalAll();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
}

static class Producer implements Runnable {
    Observed observed;
    ReentrantLock lock;
    Condition condition;

    Producer(Observed observed, ReentrantLock lock, Condition condition) {
        this.observed = observed;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                if (observed.getFilled() == true) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("producer waiting");
                        condition.await();
                        System.out.println("produced");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    observed.setFilled(true);
                    condition.signalAll();
                }else{
                    observed.setFilled(true);
                    condition.signalAll();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
    Producer producer = new Producer(observed, lock, condition);
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer(observed, lock, condition);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(producer);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(consumer);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}
```

}

Comment: Are you required to implement the pattern in this fashion?  A `BlockingQueue` would be much cleaner

Comment: I am not required to implement it in this fashion, thanks for your suggestion of using blocking queue, will try that

Answer (score 3):

Following is one more sample code for producer-consumer problem using ReentrantLock & Condition. Just in case if someone wants.

```
package reentrant_prodcons;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Reentrant_ProdCons {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Queue<Integer> queue=new LinkedList<Integer>();
        ReentrantLock lock=new ReentrantLock();
        Condition con=lock.newCondition();
        final int size = 5;

        new Producer(lock, con, queue, size).start();
        new Consumer(lock, con, queue).start();

    }

}


class Producer extends Thread{

    ReentrantLock  lock;
    Condition con;
    Queue<Integer> queue;
    int size;

    public Producer(ReentrantLock lock, Condition con, Queue<Integer> queue, int size) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.con = con;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.size=size;
    }


    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            lock.lock();
            while(queue.size()==size){
                try {
                    con.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            queue.add(i);
            System.out.println("Produced : "+i);
            con.signal();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}

class Consumer extends Thread{


    ReentrantLock lock;
    Condition con;
    Queue<Integer> queue;


    public Consumer(ReentrantLock lock, Condition con, Queue<Integer> queue) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.con = con;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
           lock.lock();
           while(queue.size()<1){
               try {
                   con.await();
               } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }
           }
            System.out.println("Consumed : "+queue.remove());
            con.signal();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the lock is acquired and con.await() is called, how will the other thread get the lock? Please explain.

Comment: con.await(); will release the lock and go to waiting status. Since the lock is free other thread can acquire it.

Comment: Am i right in saying this could reach deadlock if there are multiple consumers and producers. `cond.signal()` wakes one thread, if that thread is of the same type (producer/consumer) it may still need to keep waiting. using `cond.signalall()` would solve this problem. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps. You can easily check overflow/underflow conditions in the code by changing the consumer/producer wait time.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/*
   Re-entrant Locks can be acquired again by the same thread and the thread 
   keeps a count of that.
   Then that thread has to unlock it same number of times.

   normally usually it is only once.

   unlock should be called in finally and code should be in try block.

   This also has a wait in form of Condition.await(). (which obviouly should be 
   called inside a locked/synchronized block)

   This is basically helpful to avoid deadlocks which we will see in next 
   program

 */
public class ReentrantLock1 {

private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private static Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

private static Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>() ;
private static int maxQueueSize = 10;

private static int consumer_wait_time = 00;
private static int producer_wait_time = 300;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> producer());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> consumer());

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void producer() {
    int i = 1 ;
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(producer_wait_time);
            lock.lock();
            if(queue.size() == maxQueueSize)
                condition.await();
            queue.add(i);
            i++;
            condition.signal();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}

private static void consumer() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(consumer_wait_time);
            lock.lock();
            System.out.print("queue size is: "+ queue.size());
            if(queue.size()==0)
                condition.await();
            int i = queue.peek();
            queue.remove();
            System.out.println("Element on top is: "+i);
            condition.signal();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //unlock should be called in finally and code should be in try block.
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    /**
     *
     * @author sakshi
     */
    public class ReentrantLockDemo {

        static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        static Condition ProdCons = lock.newCondition();

      static class Producer extends Thread {

            List<Integer> list;
            Producer(List<Integer> list) {
                this.list = list;

            }

            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    lock.lock();

                    if (list.size() >=1) {
                        try {
                            ProdCons.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ReentrantLockDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }

                    list.add(i);
                    System.out.println("produce="+i);
                     ProdCons.signalAll();

                      lock.unlock(); 

                }

            }

        }

        static class Consumer extends Thread {

            List<Integer> list;


            Consumer(List<Integer> list) {
                this.list = list;

            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                      lock.lock();
                    while (list.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            ProdCons.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ReentrantLockDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }

                        System.out.println("consume=" +list.remove(0));
                        ProdCons.signalAll();

                        lock.unlock();
                    }

            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Producer produce = new Producer(list);
            Consumer consume = new Consumer(list);
            produce.start();
            consume.start();
        }
    }


output:
produce=0
consume=0
produce=1
consume=1
produce=2
consume=2
produce=3
consume=3
produce=4
consume=4
produce=5
consume=5
produce=6
consume=6
produce=7
consume=7
produce=8
consume=8
produce=9
consume=9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class prodConsumeJava8 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> que=new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        final Runnable singleproducer = () ->{
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
                    que.put(i);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        final Runnable singleConsumer = () ->{

            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Consumer"+que.take());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        new Thread(singleproducer).start();
        new Thread(singleConsumer).start();

    }

}
```