# Getting deadlock while using ReentrantLock

Tags: java, multithreading

im implementing producer consumer problem using ReentrantLock

```
public class Processor {
   Lock lock =  new ReentrantLock(true);
   Condition condn = lock.newCondition();
    public void produce() throws InterruptedException{
       lock.lock();
            System.out.println("inside producer method");
            condn.await();
            System.out.println("thread again wakeup");
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException{
          lock.lock();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            condn.signal();
            System.out.println("will i ever be ok ");
            lock.unlock();
    }


}
```

There are two methods  synchronized by ReentrantLock , but sometimes the process got Deadlocked with

o/p
will i ever be ok 
inside producer method

while running heap dump

Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 cpu=0.26ms elapsed=540.35s tid=0x00007fd5f186f800 nid=0x4603 waiting on condition  [0x0000700002357000]

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@11.0.1/Reference.java:241)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@11.0.1/Reference.java:213)

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 cpu=0.67ms elapsed=540.35s tid=0x00007fd5f1883000 nid=0x4303 in Object.wait()  [0x000070000245a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000787f08f80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x0000000787f08f80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@11.0.1/Finalizer.java:170)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 cpu=0.34ms elapsed=540.27s tid=0x00007fd5f1884000 nid=0x3903 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"Thread-0" #12 prio=5 os_prio=31 cpu=1.72ms elapsed=540.07s tid=0x00007fd5f00c7000 nid=0xa303 waiting on condition  [0x0000700002d75000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000787ed4030> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.1/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.1/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
    at Processor.produce(Processor.java:11)
    at RunnableExample$1.run(RunnableExample.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.1/Thread.java:834)
```

why is it getting deadlock even after i release the lock using

```
    condn.signal();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Producer Consumer scenario with Reentrant Lock and Condition in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065347/producer-consumer-scenario-with-reentrant-lock-and-condition-in-java)

Comment: @oleg.cherednik None of the answers on that question really provide an answer, but just dump code. I don't think it is helpful to close as duplicate to such a question.

Answer (score 1):

If a consumer calls `consume` first then a producer calls `produce`, then the producer will miss the `signal` and get stuck.

Comment: how to avoid it

Comment: I would suggest to not reinvent the wheel, use a `BlockingQueue` provided by JDK. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: ... or simply use `synchronized`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Phaser` for that. The point is that with `Phaser` producer asks "did I miss some consumption?" if no it is waiting for that if yes it is immediately proceeds further. Here is an example:

```
public class Processor {
   private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
   private volatile int lastPhaseId = 0;

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException{
            System.out.println("inside producer method");
            lastPhaseId = phaser.awaitAdvance(lastPhaseId);
            System.out.println("thread again wakeup");
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            phaser.arrive();
            System.out.println("will i ever be ok ");
    }
}
```

This works in case of a single consumer. If multiple consumer is assumed the `phase.arrive()` needs mutual exclusion access and/or registered parties changed accordingly (depends on what semantic you need)